# Git - 2 repositories

Tags: git, github, git-bash

## What I want to achieve?

I have 2 repositories (GitHub):

1. first,
2. second.

Both share an identical folder `/root` with 1 `.git` subfolder.

`/root` has `/root/a` and `/root/b` subfolders.

So folder tree looks like:

1. /root/a
2. /root/b
3. /root/.git

But I want that `/root/b` will be invisible for `second` repository (GitHub).

### How?

Comment: What's your actual problem here? What issue are you facing with this? You can't have two repositories in one folder as far as I know?

Comment: not related to `GitHub` and `git-bash` tags at all

Comment: @Seth -  answer(s) is "structuring" and "DRY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You **must** to stop thinking about *repositories* as about *folders and subfolders* (`.git` and others). You have to operate only one entity - repository (which is "repository storage per se (`.git` directory)" and "Working Directory" (may doesn't exist in "bare repositories") as parent-dir of local storage)
2. You **must** to understand, that for outer space Git-repo exist as single atomic entity and none of it's subpaths can be addressed and used (contrary to, f.e. SVN, there any subtree is usable 1-st class citizen)

Both 1+2 means: you can have or:

- just *nested* repository(ies) `root` (which internally have `/b` subfolder) in `first` and `second` repos
- [submodule feature](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) used for linking some external repository into tree of `first` and `second` repos

and you have to identify, what case is *your case*.

Pure 2 have to show you **The Right Way (tm)** for achieving goal:

- `root` repo have to be split on two (`root` without `b` and only `b`)
- `first` and `second` have to get personalized sets of submodules (`root` in `first` and `root`, `b` in `second`) - and I can't to say now, can `root` and `b` both be submodules of `first` or `b` have to be "submodule of submodule", you have to learn it by yourself

HTH